# How do I get the value of a button to pass back to the server when using JQuery & AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, Razor, C#, JQuery and AJAX.

I am using an Ajax call to postback a form to the server. I get all the form element values being passed back to the controller in:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product myProduct, string actionType)

    if (actionType == "Save")
       save....
```

And in the View I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RA", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "editForm", @id = "frmEdit" }))
```

Form Elements:

```
<td>
@Html.HiddenFor(p=>p.Id) 
<button type="submit" name="actionType" value="Save" >Save</button>
</td>
<td>@Html.EditFor(p=>p.Name)</td>
```

Some Ajax:

```
    $('.editForm').on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $('#frmEdit').serialize(),          
        context: $('button', this).closest('tr'),
        success: function (result) {
            $(this).html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now I think the problem line is since I have seen quite a few posts about problem with JQuery and submitting button values:

```
        data: $('#frmEdit').serialize(),
```

But I cannot get the button to submit an actionType of "Save". I just get null.

Thoughts greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

My code seems to interfere with my JQuery listener ?? My code is:

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Save" onclick="document.getElementById('actionType').value = 'Save';"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button.

However you can add it by hand:

```
data: $('#frmEdit').serialize() + '&actionType=Save',
```

or

```
data: $('#frmEdit').serialize() 
    + '&'
    + encodeURIComponent(button.name)
    + '='
    + encodeURIComponent(button.value),
```

where `button` is the `<button>` DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for this. What happens with this code if I have 2 buttons ie "Save" and "Close" where actionType="Save" and "Close" respectively.

Comment: @SamJolly Well, this code does not really care about that. The second variation adds the values for any button element that you store in the `button` variable. You have to do it by hand, so you decide what happens when there are 2 buttons. You can check which button was clicked and use that for example.

Comment: @SamJolly You can also use a hidden input, serialize will recognize that one. When one of the buttons is clicked, you add its value to the hidden input :).

Comment: Yes I think the hidden field may be the simplest way since I also have a button to Save and a dropdown which does an autopostback with an onClick JS event. I quess I need to assign hidden field the new value ie document.getElementById("actionType").value = "Save"

Comment: It seems that my JS interferes with my JQuery AJAX. See update to my question above for code.

Comment: May not be true, just analysing via Fiddler.